# Magento2 - Changes to Order Summary block are not appearing

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

When I edit the Order Summary block, I do not see my changes.

I even modified the vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.phtml template directly for testing purposes.

I already tried:

- flushing the Magento cache, by running *bin/magento cache:flush*
- clearing *var/generation*, *var/cache* and *var/page_cache*
- running *bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy*.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Varnish FPC and/or production mode? You may have to re-deploy all of it again.

Try clearing pub/static, deploy static files again and re-do production mode if you are using it.

You can also use the magento commands (via bin/ of your Magento 2 install) to clean the caches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited the question to make it clear that I flush the cache using bin/magento. I will try clearing pub/static.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution !

I turns out, the default locale for the project was set to fr_CA but the deploy command only deployed en_US static files when we do not provide the locale.

So, the solution is simply to call *bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_CA*.